# Why Coldline storage costs more than nearline storage in cloud computing?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, azure-storage, cloud-storage

I'm working on Data Solution using Cloud where we need to reduce the cost by choosing right storage solution.

There are number of articles/blogs which helps us understand lifecycle policy in cloud storage and cost associated with nearline and coldline storage.

But wondering, what happens technically at these cloud providers end which makes these coldline storage costlier than nearline ?

Answer (score 2):

Coldline is cheaper in terms of storage costs. Otherwise cost depends on usage patterns, [operations and data retrieval are more expensive](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) for coldline.

Also, important point that could be affected by lifecycle policies is **early deletion fee**. For coldline you will pay at least for 90 days of storage. For example if you delete objects manyally or via lifecycle policy after 10 days, early deletion fee aplies as cost of 80 days of storage. See "[Retrieval and early deletion](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing?hl=en#archival-pricing)".

Answer (score 1):

Cold storage doesn't require the same level of availability and performance. The infrastructure can be specifically setup to accomodate that type of data which results in lower storage costs, but higher transactional costs.

Those costs/savings are passed onto the customers. It's up to them to decide which type of storage fits the best for their requirements. If you have data that's accessed infrequently the cold storage will likely be cheaper and the better option as long as the availability of cold storage fits your requirements.